# iOS 8 JavaScriptCore: Where do you place your JavaScript files at?

Tags: javascript, ios, swift, javascriptcore

How do you add a JS file to the home directory so that 's' does not return 'nil'. Thanks.

```
func analyzeText(text: String) {

    let homeDir = NSHomeDirectory()

    var err: NSError? = NSError()

    let s = String(contentsOfFile: homeDir + "/text.js", encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: &err)

    println(s)

    var context = JSContext(virtualMachine: JSVirtualMachine())

    context.evaluateScript(s)

    let analyzeText = context.objectForKeyedSubscript("analyzeText")

    let analyzeTextVal = analyzeText.callWithArguments([text])

    println(analyzeTextVal)

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code works for me:

```
func analyzeText(scriptName: String) {
    var ext = scriptName.pathExtension
    var fileName = scriptName.substringToIndex(
        advance(scriptName.startIndex, 
                scriptName.utf16Count - ext.utf16Count - 1))

    if fileExtension.utf16Count == 0 {
        fileName = scriptName
        ext = "js"
    }

    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        .URLForResource(fileName, withExtension: ext)
    let scriptCode = String(contentsOfURL: url!, 
                            encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, 
                            error: nil)!

    var context = JSContext(virtualMachine: JSVirtualMachine())
    context.evaluateScript(scriptCode)
    /* ... */
}
```

To evaluate a file called `text.js`, do the following:

`analyzeText("text")`

Be sure to have added `text.js` to the Xcode project copying the file if necessary to the destination

Comment: What if there are many javascript files and they have interdependencies: can they be loaded sequentially in reverse order of their dependencies and expect to resolve properly?