# Loading many javascript files with interdependencies into a JavaScriptCore context

Tags: swift, javascriptcore

The following Q&A illustrates how to load a single `javascript` file into `JavaScriptCore`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/26979233/1056563

```
func analyzeText(scriptName: String) {
    var ext = scriptName.pathExtension
    var fileName = scriptName.substringToIndex(
        advance(scriptName.startIndex, 
                scriptName.utf16Count - ext.utf16Count - 1))

    if fileExtension.utf16Count == 0 {
        fileName = scriptName
        ext = "js"
    }

    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        .URLForResource(fileName, withExtension: ext)
    let scriptCode = String(contentsOfURL: url!, 
                            encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, 
                            error: nil)!

    var context = JSContext(virtualMachine: JSVirtualMachine())
    context.evaluateScript(scriptCode)
    /* ... */
}
```

What if there are many javascript files and they have interdependencies: can they be loaded sequentially in reverse order of their dependencies and expect to resolve properly?

1. `utils.js`
2. `file1NeedingUtils.js`
3. `file2NeedingFile1.js`

So then :

```
func analyzeText(jsContext: JSContext, scriptName: String) {
    var ext = scriptName.pathExtension
    var fileName = scriptName.substringToIndex(
        advance(scriptName.startIndex, 
                scriptName.utf16Count - ext.utf16Count - 1))

    if fileExtension.utf16Count == 0 {
        fileName = scriptName
        ext = "js"
    }

    let url = NSBundle.mainBundle()
        .URLForResource(fileName, withExtension: ext)
    let scriptCode = String(contentsOfURL: url!, 
                            encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, 
                            error: nil)!

    jsContext.evaluateScript(scriptCode)
}
var jsCtx = JSContext(virtualMachine: JSVirtualMachine())


["utils.js","file1NeedingUtils.js","file2NeedingFile1.js"]
      .forEach( x in analyzeScript(jsCtx, x))
```

Notice that we are *sharing the same JSContext* across all the invocations.

That functionality is typically the domain of the browser to handle.  I am planning to go that route but am wondering if there were likely to be issues . In addition are there optimizations to the process that would be helpful?

Comment: What did you figure out?  Was this approach successful?

Comment: @MikeR  There was no easy way. I had to construct the js files carefully.